# How to get Visual Studio Code intellisense to complete methods and set cursor inside ( ) after hitting tab

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Packages and methods in Visual Studio Code all auto complete after hitting tab (Golang), which is great, but I want it to complete the method and then put the cursor inside the ( ).  I had it working like this on another machine but I can't seem to find setting/extension that does this.

Example:

// before hitting tab

**fmt.Pri**

// after hitting tab

**fmt.Println**

// would like this after hitting tab (with cursor inside parenthesis)

**fmt.Println()**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it.  Inside your settings.json you need the following line.

```
{
        "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true, 
}
```

I have the Go ms-vscode.go extension enabled, not sure if this is relevant but just in case.

Comment: Go: Use Language Server setting will also break this on my Windows 10 Visual Studio Code. I thought I would share.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues about this on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1021). Seems they don't want to implement it as standard because it would interfere when you want to type a function reference instead of a function call.

VSCode extensions can provide "snippets", which insert code based on a prefix and include the concept of [tab stops](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops). This is not really what you're looking for but I'll draw your attention to it anyway.

You can implement more advanced functionality with a [language server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server) that listens for events in the document. If you wanted to write it yourself, I think you would need to create a language server extension.